# Yii2 activeCheckboxList style

Tags: css, checkbox, yii2, checkboxlist

I have an activeCheckboxList but the CSS styling for individual checkboxes  won't work.

```
<div class="form-label"><?= Yii::t('my', 'Status') ?></div>
                <?= Html::activeCheckboxList($model, 'status', $model->my_getStatusOptions(),
                [
                'itemOptions' => [ 'class' => 'mycheckbox',
                       'labelOptions' => [
                           'style' => 'font-weight: normal',
                           'class' => 'Checkbox',
                          ],
                 ],
                 ]
                )
             ?>
```

Comment: can you give more informations? this seems to work, I c/p your code and changed style to 'color: red;' and checkbox labels are red

Comment: Yes, the labels style can be customized, but I need to customize the checkboxes(the size of the square)

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can use your own template for one checkbox item

```
<?= Html::activeCheckboxList($model, 'status', $model->my_getStatusOptions(),
    [
        'item' => function ($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return
                "<label class='checkbox-label'>
                    {$label}
                    <input type='checkbox' name='{$name}' value='{$value}' checked='{$checked}'>
                </label>";
        }
    ]
)
?>
```